# change label text in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to change label's text by using `javascript`:

```
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function updateLabel() {
            var lblElement = document.getElementbyId("Label2");
            lblElement.innerHtml("new");
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

I call this script from the code behind:

```
mainPage.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "MyKey", "updateLabel();",true);
```

It's not working...

Using a buildin trigger like button click won't work for me that's whyI'm trying to find a way to do it with javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function updateLabel() {
       document.getElementById('Label2').innerHTML = 'New';
   }
</script>
```

Comment: to test the script i called it from button click function. when i call it from another function it looks like the page doesn't refresh. is there a way to make it work?

Comment: @AjayPunekar  , 
 **Thanks  for the code, but it isnt working for me 
my code**
<script type="text/javascript" >
        function Change_lab() {
            alert("working")
                        document.getElementById('Label2').innerHTML = 'New';
            alert("working again")  
        }
    </script>

**I only get the first alert**

**My asp Code:**

<asp:button ID="Button2" runat="server" text="chane label" 
        onclientclick="Change_lab()" />

Thanks in advance. this would really help me

Comment: @AjayPunekar** my code now is working
i changed **
 var lblElement = document.getElementById("<%=Label2.ClientID%>")

**Thank you and hope it helps someone**

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<head runat="server">
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function updateLabel() {
        var lblElement = document.getElementbyId("Label2");
        lblElement.innerText="new";
    }
 </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

**JS**:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function updateLabel()
          {
           document.getElementbyId("Label2").innerHTML= "new" ;
          }
    </script>
```

Comment: Sorry. I missed the CAPs

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is CaSe SeNsItIvE, the property is `innerHTML` NOT `innerHtml`, and it is a property not a method so you need `lblElement.innerHTML = "new";`. Also unless you are running .NET 4 or later and have ClientIDMode="Static" in your `@page` directive  you will have to take into account the actual ID that is rendered in the HTML:

```
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function updateLabel() {
            var lblElement = document.getElementbyId('<%=Label2.ClientID%>");
            lblElement.innerHTML = 'new';
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code :

```
$('#lblId').text('text which you want to append dynemically');
```